# Linq and ListView and Contains

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table 'Assets', and a 'ListView' (assetCategoriesListView) filled with Categories.

I'm trying to select all assets with the category selection:

```
Assets myAsset = dbLinqManager.db.Assets.Where(a => assetCategoriesListView.CheckedIndices.Contains(a.Category)).First();
```

But it seems that Contains can't be used. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You can use `Contains`, but only with a list of a simple type: http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/

Answer (score 1):

You're stuck in a time anachronism.  The ListView class dates from .NET 1.0, the dark days before generics became available.  The CheckedIndices property is of type  ListView.CheckedIndexCollection, it only implements IEnumerable, not IEnumerable<>.  Which is why Contains() doesn't work.

You can normally fix it by using the Cast() extension method.  But CheckedIndices contains integers, not objects.  CheckedItems contains ListViewItems.  It isn't otherwise clear how you plan to map them to 'Assets'.  Focus on keeping the data separate from the view.

Comment: So I try this:

 Assets test = dbLinqManager.db.Assets.Where(a => (assetCategoriesListView.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>()).Contains(a.Category)).First();

But I still have an error :s

Comment: You missed my second paragraph, you are trying to map integers to categories.

Comment: But myCategories are type of int

Comment: The ListViewItem's index matches the Category?  Sounds very unlikely.  I cannot chase down a compile error without knowing the error message and having some idea what Assets looks like.  Update your question with a code that I can compile and produces the same error message.

Comment: Assets is a table via DBLinq with 4 column (ID, PAth, Name, Category) of types (int,string,string,int).

Comment: And For the error: without the Cast I got: "The method or operation is not implemented" and with the Cast I got: "S0548: Can't analyze Contains() method"

Comment: "S0548" is not a standard compiler error message.  Clearly you are not using a Microsoft Linq provider.  Sounds like you'll need help from Google, keep your eye on this bug report: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/issues/detail?id=163